# Gradle checkDebugManifest failing

Tags: java, android, debugging, gradle, buildozer

I'm running buildozer, and gradle returns the error:

```
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 32.0.0-rc1
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[DEBUG]:    > Task :checkDebugManifest FAILED
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    A problem was found with the configuration of task ':checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
[DEBUG]:      - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckManifest' property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:        Reason: A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:        Possible solutions:
[DEBUG]:          1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
[DEBUG]:          2. Annotate with @InputDirectory for directories.
[DEBUG]:          3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED in 57s
[DEBUG]:    1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

The [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Input.html) nor other discussions over the matter have been helpful. Where should the changes described be made?